# Can any of the Rings of Power be passed down from their wielder?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

As the title suggests, can the Rings of Power be passed from one wielder to another? For example, can Galadriel pass down Nenya to someone?

Comment: Bilbo passed down the One ring to Frodo. Does that count? Also Aragorn had a ring, and he surely wasn't around when they were created.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I didn't think Aragorn's ring was one of the particular Rings of Power, just a special ring with some great historic significance for the Elves.

Comment: Yeah, Aragorn's ring was the Ring of Barahir.  It dated from the First Age and while it was a royal heirloom, it had absolutely no power to give its wearer.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 fair enough, just wanted to point out that rings in general were passed down.

Answer (score 50):

Not only *could* they, they were.

The Three were originally given (by Celebrimbor, their maker, one presumes) to Gil-galad and Galadriel. But only Galadriel kept hers: Gil-galad gave his two to Elrond and Círdan, who gave his to Gandalf.

> But at the end it became known that they had been held at first by the three greatest of the Eldar: Gil-galad, Galadriel and Círdan. Gil-galad before he died gave his ring to Elrond; Círdan later surrendered his to Mithrandir. For Círdan saw further and deeper than any other in Middle-earth, and he welcomed Mithrandir at the Grey Havens, knowing whence he came and whither he would return.
>   (LotR, Appendix B)
>
> At this time the first Council was held, and it was there determined that an Elvish stronghold in the east of Eriador should be maintained at Imladris rather than in Eregion. At that time also Gil-galad gave Vilya, the Blue Ring, to Elrond, and appointed him to be his vice-regent in Eriador; but the Red Ring he kept, until he gave it to Cirdan when he set out from Lindon in the days of the Last Alliance. ’ ’
>   (Unfinished Tales, The History of Galadriel and Celeborn)

Thror also gave his son Thrain his Ring of Power, one of the Seven:

> Years afterwards Thrór, now old, poor, and desperate, gave to his son Thráin the one great treasure he still possessed, the last of the Seven Rings, and then he went away with one old companion only, called Nár. Of the Ring he said to Thráin at their parting:
>
> ‘This may prove the foundation of new fortune for you yet, though that seems unlikely. But it needs gold to breed gold.’
>   (LotR, Appendix B)

Of course, Bilbo also passed on the One to Frodo!

> ‘No, don't give the ring to me,’ said Gandalf. ‘Put it on the mantelpiece. It will be safe enough there, till Frodo comes. I shall wait for him.’
>
> Bilbo took out the envelope, but just as he was about to set it by the clock, his hand jerked back, and the packet fell on the floor. Before he could pick it up, the wizard stooped and seized it and set it in its place. A spasm of anger passed swiftly over the hobbit's face again. Suddenly it gave way to a look of relief and a laugh.
>
> ‘Well, that's that,’ he said. ‘Now I'm off!’
>   (LotR, Fellowship of the Ring)

Comment: Actually, I think Celebrimbor gave Gil-galad both Narya and Vilya, and Gil-galad passed the Ring of Fire on to Cirdan.  It is also worth noting that Gil-galad probably never *wore* the Ring of Water, since from the time Gil-galad received the rings until shortly after his death, Sauron was still in possession of the One Ring, which would have given Sauron power over anything done with the Three and the ability to read the minds of their wearers.

Comment: That comports with my recollection (that C. gave G. two), but I couldn't recall the source; will edit when/if I find it. The latter statement I think is ambiguous depending on what you read: the appendices make it seem as if that's the sequence of events, but 'Of the Rings of Power and the Third Ages' repeatedly uses 'they' and 'them' and that 'they took off their rings' and  'never again used them openly while Sauron kept the ruling ring.' *Galadriel and Celeborn* references the first timeline, but then implies Galadriel did benefit from the power of the Ring.

Comment: Certainly, come to think of it, there may have been benefits to merely *possessing* the Three: Frodo and Sam benefit from the power of the One merely by possession on a few occasions. Perhaps it was in this manner that they did not 'openly' use the Three while still employing them indirectly in some way.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that freely giving away the One Ring was near impossible. Only Bilbo ever managed to do it. And both Galadriel and Gandalf refused to take the ring, fearing they couldn't get rid of it.

Comment: @JollyJoker And even Bilbo needed some assistance from Gandalf. If Bilbo had picked up the envelope from the floor in stead of Gandalf it is debatable if he would have had the strength of will to do it again. From the passage quoted by Shamshiel it is clear the One Ring was doing its best to manipulate him.

Comment: @JollyJoker You forgot about Sam - Although he didn't possess the ring for long, he freely gave it back to Frodo

Comment: @EugeneStyer: I'd forgotten about Sam, that's a good one to add in there!

Comment: It is rare that I disagree with such an upvoted answer. Anyone who would ask such a question surely knows that the possession of, at least the one ring, was passed down. But just because the possession was passed down didn't change the ownership of the ring in the sense that it still served Sauron.

Comment: @IKnowNothing: The question is not whether or not a Ring would serve Sauron, but whether or not it could be passed on and wielded by another, which is a 'yes, even the One Ring.' At any rate, the Three were untainted, and the Seven did not directly serve Sauron's purposes, and the One could hypothetically have been wrested from him, effectively killing him, even if the nature of the Ring (domination of wills) led to further evils.

Comment: @Shamshiel but how could anyone not know that already while caring enough to ask the question?

Comment: @Iknownothing: look at the edit history, OP’s kid asked the question and he’s new to the ‘fandom‘.

Comment: I am not aware of any detail of Celebrimbor giving two rings to Gil-galad. I'm only familiar with Gil-Galad and Cirdan each receiving one initially. Does anyone actually have a source for that?

Comment: @eques: It's from Unfinished Tales' *Galadriel and Celeborn*, which is hard to reconcile in certain respects with other works, but I can't see any reason to doubt the detail about Gil-galad: indeed it makes a little more sense than the proud Noldorin Celebrimbor handing over one of the Three to the (Telerin) Cirdan; indeed one imagines, like Michael Martinez writes, that the Noldor were loth from guilt and shame to spread even the story of the Rings very widely.

Comment: The problem is partially reconciling the different threads of stories among Tolkien's writings. The Unfinished Tales as the name suggests are likely in earlier states and thus agree less with the final versions in the Lord of the Rings/the Hobbit.

Comment: @eques: The passage in question was written *after* the publication of the Lord of the Rings. Most of the Unfinished Tales are in fact later writings. Indeed, one part of the published *Galadriel and Celeborn* is likely the last thing Tolkien ever wrote on the LotR universe. As C. Tolkien notes, the story in general is problematic: even Appendix B is hard to reconcile with Galadriel's words in FoTR.

Comment: Been a while since I've read Fellowship, but didn't Tom Bombadil give up the One Ring?

Comment: @Zenzizenzizenzic He did, but he wasn't affected by it in any capacity. I chime in to say Frodo tried to give the ring away. . . at first.